# How can I get particular account Details from Account in iOS

Tags: account, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, account-management, mobilepush-ios

Using the salesforce sdk I am looking to fetch account details using salesforce sdk which is based on login account,

If I login with test@salesforce.com

then I want to fetch all details of account test@salesforce.com.

there is SFRestRequest by which I can get account details but I am unable to find only logged in account details using SF API,

Comment: Hey Sandeep. Did my answer help you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you say "Account" with an email address and login, you may be referring to the `User` object?

You can issue a SOQL query for the `User` object just like any other record. Check out your org's schema for details on the fields available on `User`.

Comment: thanks @Jonathan Hersh for your reply can you guide me how I can get Org schema and particular user (which is logged in)

Answer (score 0):

A user detail of the current user is stored in SFIdentityData object. For example, the current user name can be retrieved so,

```
#import "SFIdentityData.h"

NSString *userName = [SFAccountManager sharedInstance].idData.username;
```

Comment: The latest SDK doesnt have SFAccountManager. Which class replaced this SFAccountManager? Currently, i am trying to update the Salesforce sdk.